# Successive intern calls in sequence diagrams

Tags: uml, diagram, sequence-diagram

I'm creating some sequence diagram and i want to detail my calls, but there is a class which call successively intern functions, would it be ok if i draw it this way:

[image]

If not how could i do ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's syntactically simply wrong. You would use a Loop Fragment:

[image]

`funcA` is an internal call. Inside the two operations `funcB` and `funcC` will be called in a loop which is guarded by the condition `some condition`. This could as well be `N times` or whatever constraints the loop.

Comment: I dont get how i could represent it on a loop ? I'd like to represent this kind of calls : func1(){
 func2()
 func3()
}